# Moq, evaluate a boolean expression in Verify(()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Ok right, I'm trying to learn a bit about Moq and something puzzles me.

I can setup a verify method to check if a method has been called, and this works perfectly. But I'd like to try something else:

So, this is fine:

```
mockNoteContext.Verify(ctx => ctx.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);
```

But I try to stretch it a bit to do more checks:

```
mockNoteContext.Verify(ctx => ctx.Notes.Count() == 1);
```

Doesn't work, so I started playing around a bit and got the following:

```
Expression<Func<NoteContext, bool>> expr = ctx => ctx.Notes.Count() == 1;
mockNoteContext.Verify(It.Is<Expression<Func<NoteContext, bool>>>(e => e == expr));
```

Which just gives a null value exception. But I don't understand why. Probably it doesn't know what to do with 'e'?. This all feels clunky to boot. How can I set this up properly?

Of course I know I can just read:

```
var noteCount = mockNoteContext.Object.Notes.Count();
```

And Assert with that, but I'm just curious how I could leverage `Verify` to handle this for me :)

Any help is welcome!

Comment: That is not how to use the Verify call. It is used to verify if a member on the mock was invoked. not to assert values. check documentation https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#verification

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve? Provide more context about what you are trying to test and maybe more help can be provided

Comment: Ok, thanks for this :) shouldve look there before spending this time :).
My goal was and is basically to learn more about moq, so I can use it for unit testing.

Comment: Just to add an alternative option to Nkosi's "Fluent Assertions" suggestion, [NUnit](http://nunit.org/) is a widely-used unit testing framework. With that, you could write `Assert.That(mockNoteContext.Object.Notes, Has.Count.EqualTo(1))`, which is also quite a natural way of specifying the expected outcome. Or you could stick with `Assert.That(mockNoteContext.Object.Notes,Count(), Is.EqualTo(1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how to use the `Verify` call. It is used to verify if a member on the mock was invoked. Not to assert values.

Review the documentation https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#verification

What you suggested at the end of your question is the advised way to assert values.

```
var expected = 1;
var noteCount = mockNoteContext.Object.Notes.Count();
Assert.AreEqual(expected, noteCount);
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the mocking framework.

There are also libraries that are used specifically for assertions.

One such library is [Fluent Assertions](http://fluentassertions.com/)

> Fluent Assertions is a set of .NET extension methods that allow you to more naturally specify the expected outcome of unit tests.

for example

```
var expected = 1;
var noteCount = mockNoteContext.Object.Notes.Count();
noteCount.Should().Be(expected); //<-- fluent assertion
```

The two libraries can be used together to help when testing.